# Create pdf documents with 2D barcodes from .NET

Tags: .net, pdf, barcode

How can I create pdf documents with 2D barcodes (for example QR code http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_Code) from .NET application?

I will (probably) use iTextSharp for creating the documents. Which component should I use for drawing 2D barcodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you not create an Image with the bar code and embed it into the PDF?

Answer (score 3):

iTextSharp supports several barcode standards (as per the tutorial at http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch09.html)

```
* Barcode39:  code 39 and code 39 extended
* Barcode128: code 128 and the special encoding UCC/EAN-128
* BarcodeEAN: EAN13, EAN8, UPCA, UPCE, and EAN with supplemental 5, EAN with supplemental 5, EAN with supplemental 2
* BarcodeInter25: interleaved 2 of 5
* BarcodePostnet: postnet and planet
```

Comment: whoops...that makes my answer suck :/

Comment: Yeah, almost perfect answer :)

Comment: Dan's answer is probably best since there is no native iTextSharp method for 2D

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Aspose barcode](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.barcode-for-.net/default.aspx) and [Aspose pdf](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx) components to create a series of documents with barcodes easily.

There's plenty of examples in the forum [demonstrating examples](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/44893/convert-barcode-to-image-and-place-in-pdf.aspx) of how to do this. In addition, you will also be able to extract the barcode values from the original PDF using these components if that becomes a future requirement.

Answer (score 1):

[PDFFlow library](https://go.pdfflow.io/pdfflow_information) supports barcodes including QR codes (variants 1-40, four levels of error correction available).

In your C# project, add reference to a free library **Gehtsoft.PDFFlowLib.Barcodes** from nuget.org.

**Exampe of adding QR code to a paragraph:**

```
DocumentBuilder.New()
    .AddSection()
        .AddParagraph()
            .AddQRCode("Some information for sharing",
                QRCodeEncodingMethod.Binary,
                QRCodeErrorCorrection.M,
                QRCodeVersion.Version4,
                4) .ToDocument()
    .Build("Result.pdf");
```

[image: adding QR code to a paragraph]

**Exampe of adding a QR code with a URL to a table cell:**

```
        var textUrl = "https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gehtsoft.PDFFlowLib/";
        DocumentBuilder.New()
            .AddSection()
                .AddTable()
                    .SetWidth(230)
                    .AddColumnToTable()
                    .AddColumnToTable()
                    .AddRow()
                        .AddCellToRow("QR-code in table cell")
                        .AddCell()
                            .AddQRCodeUrl(textUrl)
                                .SetWidth(150)
        .ToDocument()
            .Build("Result.pdf");
```

[image]

Here is a tutorial with many examples: [AddingQRCodes](https://go.pdfflow.io/AddingQRCodes).

Note, that Gehtsoft.PDFFlowLib.Barcodes library is an extension of [PDFFlow library](https://go.pdfflow.io/pdfflow_information) for generation PDF documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [DevExpress Reports](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/), they are supporting 2D Barcode in there reports, also they are supporting exporting the reports to a lot of formats like PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Google says http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf417lib/ though it hasn't been updated since 2005 and is in beta. Please do report back if you use this.

(Feels like 2D barcodes is quite unusual, probably because just having a ID is often sufficient and 1D-scanners are waaaay cheaper.)